# Facebook like Grid Photos Library

Tags: java, android, grid, photo

Is there any libraries aside from BitFrames to use so that I can make a Facebook like feed for photos more that 1? Because I don't know how to implement BitFrames Library on Firebase storage.

[Like This Layout](https://i.stack.imgur.com/F0kUF.png)

Comment: hope this will help you. https://github.com/abhisheklunagaria/FacebookTypeImageGrid

Comment: thank you, I'm having problem on that too, can you or someone help me how to use BitFrames? Because firebase storage is returning URI and the showBitFrame() method requires BeanImage which gives an error when i combine the two.